# Problema ao exportar dados para Excel

Tags: php, microsoft-excel

Estou com um problema na hora de exportar os dados para Excel, os campos de Numero da residencia e interpretado de maneira errada pelo EXCEL

Exemplo: se o cliente coloca no campo Numero da residencia 100 A, vai normal, mais se ele coloca abaixo de 24, tipo 23 A, o EXCEL interpreta isso como horário e coloca 23:00:00

A  mesma coisa acontece se o cliente coloca desta forma 8-10, que corresponde a Bloco 8 Ap 10, o EXCEL interpreta como data, 08/10/2016

Ja coloquei o campo de complemento, mais não adianta, o cliente ainda sim coloca informações no campo numero, limitei o campo numero apenas para números, ai o cliente coloca a mesma coisa no campo complemento, e me da o mesmo erro! :(

No banco de dados grava tudo certo, só da pau na hora de exportar.

Não estava querendo migrar para a classe PHPExcel, mais acho que se não tiver jeito terei que implantar, mais não sei se isso vai resolver!

Este e o código para gerar o XML

```
    for($i=0;$i<1;$i++){   
    $html[$i] .= "<table>";
    $html[$i] .= "<tr>";
    $html[$i] .= "<td><b>Nome</b></td>";
    $html[$i] .= "<td><b>Email</b></td>";
    $html[$i] .= "<td><b>CPF</b></td>";
    $html[$i] .= "<td><b>Cep</b></td>";
    $html[$i] .= "<td><b>Endereço</b></td>";
    $html[$i] .= "<td><b>Numero</b></td>";
    $html[$i] .= "<td><b>Complemento</b></td>";
    $html[$i] .= "<td><b>Bairro</b></td>";
    $html[$i] .= "<td><b>Cidade</b></td>";
    $html[$i] .= "<td><b>UF</b></td>";
    $html[$i] .= "<td><b>Status do cliente</b></td>";
    $html[$i] .= "</tr>";
    $html[$i] .= "</table>";
}

$i = 1;

    $html[$i] .= "<table>";
    $html[$i] .= "<tr>";
    $html[$i] .= "<td>$nome_cad_cod</td>";
    $html[$i] .= "<td>$email_cad</td>";
    $html[$i] .= "<td>$cpf_cad</td>";   
    $html[$i] .= "<td>$cep_cad</td>";
    $html[$i] .= "<td>$endereco_cad</td>";
    $html[$i] .= "<td>$numero_cad</td>";    
    $html[$i] .= "<td>$complemento_cad</td>";
    $html[$i] .= "<td>$bairro_cad</td>";
    $html[$i] .= "<td>$cidade_cad</td>";    
    $html[$i] .= "<td>$estado_cad</td>";
    $html[$i] .= "<td>Pagseguro</td>";
    $html[$i] .= "</tr>";
    $html[$i] .= "</table>";
    $i++;
}
$arquivo = 'relatorio.xls';
header ("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header ("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D,d M YH:i:s") . " GMT");
header ("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header ("Pragma: no-cache");
header ("Content-type: application/x-msexcel");
header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$arquivo}" );
header ("Content-Description: PHP Generated Data" );

for($i=0;$i<=$result->num_rows;$i++){  
    echo $html[$i];
}
```